# Runtime error while removing vector elements

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, runtime-error, binary-search

[problem solved, thx for answering]
I have a sorted vector `v` and a vector `num`, this is how I delete elements in vector `v`:

```
vector <int> v; 
vector <int> num; 
//gets input
//for an example: v = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6} 
//num.size() = 0 

num.push_back(v[v.size()-1]); //adds num "v"'s maximum element 
v.erase(v.begin()+v.size()-1); // removes that element 
while(v.size() > 0) {
    num.push_back(v.back()); //adds num "v"'s maximum element
    v.erase(v.begin()+v.size()-1); // removes that element
    for(int i = 0; i < num.size()-1; i++) // checkes all elements of num except the last one added 
    {
        int ggcd = __gcd(num[num.size()-1], num[i]); 
        int fnd = findv(v, ggcd); // finds GCD of maximum element and element i of num 
        v.erase(v.begin()+fnd); // removes
        fnd = findv(v, ggcd); //repeats one more time 
        v.erase(v.begin()+fnd);
    }
}
```

where function `findv(vector<int> v, int x)` is a function that finds the index of smallest element that is not less than `x` by binary search:

```
int findv(const vector<int>& v, int x) // simply, finds
{
    int l = 0, r = sz(v), mid; 
    while(r-l > 1)
    {
        mid = (l+r)/2; 
        if(v[mid] < x) l = mid; 
        else if(v[mid] > x) r = mid; 
        else return mid; 
    }
    return l; 
}
```

size of vector v in the start is always square of some n (4 here) so the vector size never reaches 0 in middle of the while.
The runtime error is from the `v.erase(v.begin()+fnd)` in the `for` as when I delete them, there is no runtime error and the `v.erase(v.begin()+v.size()-1)`s before the while/for work perfectly

after I found out the problem is about erasing in the for, I replaced them with `v.erase(v.begin()+0)` to see if the problem is in function findv. but that also gave me a runtime error, I replaced it with many other numbers, size-1 and everything but still, there was a runtime error. I searched a lot in internet and even tried to change how I delete elements from v but they had other errors/didnt do what I want. for an example this:

```
v.erase(remove(v.begin(), v.end(), __gcd(num[sz(num)-1], num[i])), v.end());
```

deletes by value, but it deletes all elements of that value which isnt what I want. and tried this:

```
vector<int>::iterator it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), __gcd(num[sz(num)-1], num[i]));
int index = distance(v.begin(), it);
v.erase(v.begin()+index);
it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), __gcd(num[sz(num)-1], num[i]));
index = distance(v.begin(), it);
v.erase(v.begin()+index);
```

But this one also gave me a runtime error.
the elements **dont** run out while in the while cause n^2 + 2*n + 1 = (n+1)^2 which is n^2 for another n. its provable by a mathematical induction.
Btw, if u want to know what I am exactly doing in the code, its a solution for this problem:
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/582/A and this is a full version of my code: https://ideone.com/suu0GG

Comment: Don't try to learn C++ by trial and error, specialy not from a competitive coding site. Have a look at std::min_element, don't use functions starting with `__` (two underscorres) they are internal for the compiler. And please make an effort to write readable code that also compiles in our compilers (minimal reproducible example).

Comment: Good sources to learn C++ from : [a recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or from [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) that site is decent and pretty up to date.
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for reference material (and examples). When you have done all that keep using [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with the latest best practices since C++ keeps evolving.

Comment: [OT]: `v[v.size()-1]` can simply be `v.back()`.

Comment: debugger (or logging vector content) might help to see where/when things diverge from your expectation (as empty vector, wrong index, ...).

Comment: You might pass vector by const reference to avoid copy in `findv`.

Comment: ok so I edited my code with all the things you suggested me and it worked, thx

Comment: @iliaghasemi Why didn't you use [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) or `std::upper_bound` instead of writing your own binary search function?

Comment: Function `findv` should operate on a `std::multiset` or `std::multimap`, not a `std::vector`. So somtehign is wrong with the design / idea from the start.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie someone suggested me to write algorithms by my own.

Comment: Please do not edit questions with "problem solved". Post a self-answer with what solved the issue so other can find it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not exactly find out what was actually wrong in my code but, seems like my problem was not about the erasing part and other things were wrong. I dont know why there was no runtime after removing the erase part, maybe it was a compiler error. these are things I changed to make it work:

- replaced '__gcd' function with a handmade one
- replaced unnecessarily complicated parts like 'v[v.size()-1]' with simpler and cleaner ones like 'v.back()' to avoid unwanted mistakes
- passed vector to the 'findv' function by const reference to avoid copy
- I also tried changing my compiler in case the problem isnt from me, and weirdly I faced different reactions from different compilers
- the alternative code that I used instead of what I wrote first also works perfectly after fixing these (the one which works with iterator)

also one user here asked me why did I use a hand made function 'findv' while lowerband and upperband exist and well that's a valid problem for my code. (I had reasons for it, but I am saying it generally)